# Java `DisplayMode`s bit depth on Linux is `-1`

Tags: java, linux, graphics

Well I had a problem for a while and I figured out how to solve it, but now I want to know why my solution worked. The `GraphicsDevice.setDisplayMode()` method always threw an `IllegalArgumentException` on my Linux system, so in order to solve it I checked every `DisplayMode` available with the `GraphicsDevice.getDisplayModes()` method. I noticed that the bit depth (returned by the `.getBitDepth()` method) was always equal to `-1`. When I changed my bit depth parameter to be `-1` the `IllegalArgumentException` was solved. But what does that `-1` mean, surely there can not be a bit depth of `-1` on any system. Does that mean that my system does not allow (Java) application to change the color bit depth inside the application?

PS.
I run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for `getBitDepth()` says:

> Returns the bit depth of the display, in bits per pixel. This may be
>   BIT_DEPTH_MULTI if multiple bit depths are supported in this display
>   mode.

If you look at the [constant field values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.DisplayMode.BIT_DEPTH_MULTI) for [java.awt.DisplayMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/DisplayMode.html), then you'll find

```
Modifier and Type          Constant Field          Value
public static final int    BIT_DEPTH_MULTI         -1
```

So `-1` implies that multiple bit depths are supported ...

Comment: Ah, of course. Strange that on my Windows System every DisplayMode had its own bit depth.